# NativeScript Hello World app size

Tags: nativescript

With the hello world app made with NativeScript, the file size is 12.3mb. In general NS app, does the file size equates install size? This is a problem in areas where internet is slow and load startup will be longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android APK file actually contains 3 separate runtimes for the three major Android device platforms.   You can change this to upload 3 separate 4mb apk's which then the google play store will automatically download the proper .apk to the proper device.

However at this point NativeScript's "default" build produces a combined 12mb apk to make it a lot simplier on you, so you can just upload a single file.

---

Update: The later versions of NativeScript only bundle two runtimes in the application.  This reduces the size by about 3.5megs, and still works on all devices (dropped the automatic inclusion of the Arm64 bit version).

---

Update for Changes in the Eco-system: Webpacking a NAN (NativeScript Angular) app will make a fairly decent difference in the size of the JavaScript code, since the Angular code base is massive.  But it doesn't make as large of a difference with a PAN (Plain Awesome NativeScript) size.   However, WebPack does make a large difference in speed of application startup, especially with a NAN app.   So, if you are building a NAN app; you really want to WebPack it.

Comment: You can use webpack to reduce size. If you want to generate separate builds check this - https://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/publishing-android-apps#apks-with-abi-splits

Comment: Webpack doesn't do a lot for the size on a normal (PAN) NativeScript app; if you are using Angular2 with NativeScript (NAN) then WebPack actually makes a diffference.   However you are still limited by the runtimes.

Comment: @Nathanael , you were correct about the thing of using Angualr2 with nativeScript to feel the difference with WebPack in the application, I was able to reduce my application run-time from 26 sec to 6 sec.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this size issue is there with nativeScript when building an application for the android.

There are 2 approach I came across:

1. Make separate builds with respect to the architecture of the android mobile.
   Here is the link to that:
   https://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/publishing-android-apps#apks-with-abi-splits

2.Use web pack to bundle all the java script files that is causing the size of the application to grow this much.
Here is the link to that:
http://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/bundling-with-webpack